# Como fazer um "insert" com Dapper usando uma classe?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, classes, dapper

Estou testando o Dapper e quando tento usar uma classe encontrei o erro:

> Must declare the scalar variable

Segue o código:

```
public class Teste
{
    public int id;
    public string nome;
    public int idade;
}

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(conexao))
        {
            Teste t = new Teste();
            t.nome = "Iago";
            t.idade = 20;

            var newTeste = db.Execute("Insert Into Teste (nome, idade) Values(@nome, @idade)", t);

            var teste = db.Query("Select * From Teste");
        }
```

Tabela:

```
Create Table Teste (

 id int identity(1,1),
 nome varchar(50),
 idade int 
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precisa ter propriedades na classe, então mude sua classe para:

```
public class Teste {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

E mude:

```
var newTeste = db.Execute("Insert Into Teste (nome, idade) Values(@Nome, @Idade)", t);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Dapper.cs).

Eu mudaria os nomes das colunas da tabela também.

Comment: Maniero, muito obrigado não tinha reparado a falta do get/set na classe. Funcionou muito bem.

Answer (score 5):

Tente usar o DynamicParameter

```
public class Teste
{
    public int id;
    public string nome;
    public int idade;
}


//Necessário referenciar o Dapper na sua classe que faz o insert...
using Dapper;

//No seu método para salvar no banco de dados...
var parametros = new DynamicParameters();
parametros.Add("Nome", teste.nome, DbType.AnsiString);
parametros.Add("Idade", teste.idade , DbType.Int32);

db.Execute("Insert into Teste (nome, idade) Values(@Nome, @Idade)", parametros);
```

Comment: Esse modo acho melhor quando tem vários parâmetros. Melhora na visualização.

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo via procedure.

```
public class Teste
{
    public int id;
    public string nome;
    public int idade;
}

using (IDbConnection Connection = GetConnection())
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Execute("nome_da_sua_procedure",
            new {
                id = classeTeste.Data,
                nome = logChamadaoEntity.Entrada,
                idade = logChamadaoEntity.Saida                           
            },
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);                    
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```